# Are private class variables instantiated for each instance of a class?

Tags: c++

When I define a variable in a class, every time I declare an instance of this class it creates, in memory, a new copy of that variable for the particular instance. I understand this, but does this hold for when all the member variables are private? For example:

```
class A {
    int a, b, c;
};

A a;
```

When I create a new instance, are these private variables still allocated for `a` even though they can't be used outside the class?

Comment: this can be found in any book or web page about c++ basics.

Comment: @MarekR My book is very confusing on its explanation on how this works. Can you please take away the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Memory allocation is an implementation detail. Consider the code:

```
class A {
    int a, b, c;
};

int main()
{
   A a;
}
```

There will probably be no memory allocation whatsoever, because C++ operates on an as-if model. Meaning, if the output is the same as the expected one, the compiler is free to do anything. Including optimizing out dead code.

Typically, though, yes, you can assume space is allocated for all members of an object.

Comment: Just a warning to the asker: you might want to read the last sentence first. Then read the rest at a later date!

Comment: @sftrabbit Don't worry, I understand what he's saying. Was just curious and never knew about this.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption that private variables "can't be used from outside of the class" is incorrect. Declaring a member `private` simply means that it can't be *directly referred by name* from outside of the class (except by class friends, of course). "Can't be used" is a much stronger assertion, that happens to be untrue.

If the "outside world" somehow obtains an alternative way to access that private member, it can do that without any restrictions. For example, your class might implement a public  access member function that returns a reference (or pointer) bound to the private member. That will make that specific member indirectly accessible from the outside.

In reality there's absolutely no difference between public and private members of the class, aside from the purely conceptual compile-time access restrictions that work at the level of *member names*. It is a very thin layer of protection implemented at the compiler level. There's nothing physical behind it, i.e. there's no physical difference between data members of the class, regardless of their protection level.

Comment: @David: Yes, it does. The "there's absolutely no difference between public and private members of the class..." is a direct and immediate answer to the question.

Comment: *are these private variables still allocated for `a` even though they can't be used outside the class?* is the question. He might've had a misconception, and you can clear that up for him, but this still doesn't answer the primary question.

Comment: @David.: No, no, no. The question is asked in the context of the previously made (by OP) assertion: "every time I declare an instance of this class it creates, in memory, a new copy of that [public] variable for the particular instance". In this context my "there's no difference..." statement directly and immediately answers the question.